# Error al instalar psycopg2 en python 3.9

Tags: python, postgresql

Hola he estado aprendiendo usar python con postgresql y visual studio
para hacer un sistema de ventas.
AHORA el problema surge cuando quiero utilizar el pip en python 3.9 para psycopg2 que me surgen errores
los cuales no aparecen cuando utilizo otro que quiero descargar solo con psycopg2.
segun los requisitos de psycopg2 debes tener un compilador c++, lo cual no sé que es, y bueno instala el microsoft visual 2019, y no resolvio el problema.
mi sistema operativo es Windows 8.1
Porfavor ayudenme, necesito para crear un sistema de ventas, gracias.
[image: ESTE ES EL ERROR QUE ME APARECE]

Comment: En las [instrucciones de instalación](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html) te explica cómo instalar sin tener que compilar: `pip install psycopg2-binary`. Es posible que el problema sea que python 3.9 no es una versión soportada por este conector. Prueba con otro (eg: PyGreSQL).

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu información, y tienes razon, no cumplo los prerrequisitos como python maximo 3.8 y postgresql como maximo 12. estoy instalando esa versiones :). @ChemaCortes